# When a managed object model updates its relationship model is not getting updated

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a feed model which is having one-many relationship with user model. When I am updating a parameter on user model on mainQueueContext, my feed model is pointing to that old user model.

Can someone help me where could be the problem?

Comment: Let me try to guess what you mean and restate your question:  *My data model has a entity named `feed` which has a one-to-many relationship with another entity named `user`.  When I update an attribute on a `user` object, …*   That's as far as I can guess.  I think you are reporting that some view is not updating.  You are probably using two managed object contexts as parent and child, and the problem is in synchronizing those.  So, first of all please verify that my restatement is correct, and then tell us more about your managed object contexts, and maybe post some code.

Comment: Yes you are right @JerryKrinock, I have already resolved it. The problem is with multiple contexts. Please add that point as an answer I will mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue issue is with both are in different context. When we use parent and child context we should make sure to save parent context also.